# Proof of Riesz-Fisher Theorem

Tags: reference-request

Can someone provide a proof or a source containing a proof of the version of the Riesz-Fisher Theorem provided here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem#Modern_forms_of_the_theorem?

Answer (score 1):

It's on page 248 of the second edition of Folland's *Real Analysis*. Check the remarks following the proof of theorem 8.20.

It's also in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Comment: I don't see a proof of it on page 248...

Comment: @Anthony Did you read the remarks following the proof of theorem 8.20? Do you have the second edition?